# web services @.net or java

Tags: java, .net, service

confusion in using either jax-ws(java) or .NET for implementing the web services. i would like to develop some web services and check the security loopholes in them(means to stimulate some attacks in SOA such as coercive parsing attack, dos attack etc..)
 Which one either Java (or) .NET will be better for programming the web services for beginners?

Comment: Which language/platform are you most comfortable with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, .net has been better at "turn-key" web-service solutions, with cohesive tool support, whereas Java web-service development has generally been seen as more complicated, but with better flexibility and interoperability.

As time has passed, these stereotypes have become less pronounced, with Java tools becoming more intuitive, and microsoft stuff becoming better at interoperability.

As for your question, if you want to analyze security holes, then picking one or the other doesn't really make sense, since they're bound to have different problems.

But if you must pick one, and you have no familiarity with either, then my guess is that you'll get further and faster using a .NET tool than a Java one (and I say that as a Java developer).

Comment: +1 for the .Net acceptance as a Java developer. I understand that C# has more integrated tooling for WS than Java (and again I say that as a Java developer)

Comment: There is a nice Web Service explorer in Eclipse JEE.  There are nice client and server wizards in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it hinges on which language and platform you're more familiar with. I would choose Java due to my years of experience on the Java platform. They'll both have the same level of support for web services - it's a question of familiarity with the tooling.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the one you're most comfortable with. There are lots of tutorials on the web for both alternatives. To get started with easy web services both platforms have good IDE support that lets you create web services almost without writing any line of code yourself.

Here is an introductory [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) using NetBeans.

Also this is quite biased, I would say that Java (tooling) is more than capable for this task.

However, it would be interesting to compare both regarding their security issues.